# Tkinter Unknown Option -menu

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I keep getting the error:

> _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-menu"

My MWE looks like:

```
from tkinter import *

 def hello():
    print("hello!")

 class Application(Frame):
    def createWidgets(self):       
       self.menuBar = Menu(master=self)
       self.filemenu = Menu(self.menuBar, tearoff=0)
       self.filemenu.add_command(label="Hello!", command=hello)
       self.filemenu.add_command(label="Quit!", command=self.quit)

    def __init__(self, master):
       Frame.__init__(self, master)
       self.pack()
       self.createWidgets()
       self.config(menu=self.menuBar)

 if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    ui = Application(root)
    ui.mainloop()
```

I'm on OS X 10.8 using python 3. Why am I getting the unknown option error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
self.config(menu=self.menuBar)
```

`menu` is not a valid configuration option for `Frame`.

Perhaps you meant to inherit from `Tk` instead?

```
from tkinter import *

def hello():
    print("hello!")

class Application(Tk):
    def createWidgets(self):       
       self.menuBar = Menu(master=self)
       self.filemenu = Menu(self.menuBar, tearoff=0)
       self.filemenu.add_command(label="Hello!", command=hello)
       self.filemenu.add_command(label="Quit!", command=self.quit)
       self.menuBar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.filemenu)

    def __init__(self):
       Tk.__init__(self)
       self.createWidgets()
       self.config(menu=self.menuBar)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ui = Application()
    ui.mainloop()
```