# why does the Menu in Tkinter produce an error

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, menu

```
class Create(Tk):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.menubar = Menu(master = self)
        self.menubar.add_command(label = "A", command= lambda: self.show_frame(A) )
        self.menubar.add_command(label = "B", command= lambda: self.show_frame(B) )
        self.menubar.add_command(label = "C", command= lambda: self.show_frame(C) )
        self.menubar.add_command(label = "D", command= lambda: self.show_frame(D) )

        self.config(menu=self.menubar)

global app
app = MainClass()
app.mainloop()
```

For reference: MainClass does lots of things but it also Calls Create, as part of this I have several frames that I will raise to show the user, this all works without the menu however I keep getting the error:

```
self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-menu"
```

I have searched this and found another stack overflow question (linked below) which said that you need to make your class inherit from Tk rather than Frame however I am still having issues with this error.

What am I missing? (I am running python version 3.8.1)

[Tkinter Unknown Option -menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22811808/tkinter-unknown-option-menu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing an instance of class `Create` to `Frame.__init__`. `Create` has been inherited from `Tk`.

Try the following:

```
class Create(Tk):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.menubar = Menu(master = self)
        self.menubar.add_command(label = "A", command= lambda: self.show_frame(A) )
        self.menubar.add_command(label = "B", command= lambda: self.show_frame(B) )
        self.menubar.add_command(label = "C", command= lambda: self.show_frame(C) )
        self.menubar.add_command(label = "D", command= lambda: self.show_frame(D) )

        self.config(menu=self.menubar)
```

Downside to this is that even though you have correctly inherited from `Tk`, 2 windows will show up, and also the `Menu` will not have a `Frame` widget as master.